# Configure custom Column Options for Serilog Sinks MsSqlServer in AppSettings.json is not working

Tags: .net-core, serilog, appsettings

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to configure the column options for serilog sink mssqlserver in the `appsettings.json` file for an ASP.Net Core 3 project.

besides not filling the custom columns, the database is also created in the standard way without these column, so I added them by hand. This could point to a configuration issue?

The SQL to create the table

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logtable](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [MessageTemplate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Level] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
        [TimeStamp] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
        [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Properties] [xml] NULL,
        [LogEvent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Controller_Name] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [Method_Name] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [StackTrace] [varchar](500) NULL
    )
```

I create and configure the logger in the `Program.cs` file.

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseSerilog()
                    .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                        .CreateLogger();
```

I can build the configuration file from the `appsettings.json` file, which contains a Serilog node with information for which connection string and table to use.

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=SWPC159; Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=True;", // connection String
          "tableName": "logtable",
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "disableTriggers": true,
            "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "Controller_Name",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 500
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "Method_Name",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 500
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "StackTrace",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 500
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing configuartion with hosting context,solve the issues

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom
            .Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
            .Build();
        }
```

Comment: Also worked for me using .net 6 Core MVC project Thanks!